# How to share expado or weakmap properties (or other options if available) cleanly

Tags: dart

Edited as the original post was impossible to understand...sorry guys.

#### Why did I want to use expando/weakmap?

I had a custom layout/sizer element that resizes children. By using expando, I wanted to control that resizing behavior without creating a strong reference.
e.g.

> ```
> var l1 = new Layout();
> var e1 = new DivElement();
> e1.text = 'The size of this element will remain as is';
>
> //setting property prior to appending to avoid resizing
> l1.add_resizable_attribute(e1,false);
> l1.append(e1);
> print(l1.isFrozen(e1));//returns true
> ```

I found a better solution, but I want to know how to map an object with data in Dart and share it across multiple objects safely and dynamically manage that.

#### Why did I want to share a expando property?

My Layout element may contain another layout element and form a tree. Allowing access to the expando property of an object anywhere in the tree seems a rational thing to do.
e.g.

> ```
> var l1 = new Layout();
> var l2 = new Layout();
>
> var e1 = new DivElement();
> e1.text = 'The size of this element will remain as is';
> l1.add_resizable_attribute(e1,false);
>
> print(l1.isFrozen(e1));//returns true
> print(l2.isFrozen(e1));//returns false as l2 is not part of the tree
>
> l1.append(l2)//forming a tree
> print(l1.isFrozen(e1));//returns true
> print(l2.isFrozen(e1));// returns true on l2 as well
>
> l2.add_resizable_attribute(e1,true);
> print(l1.isFrozen(e1));//changed on l2 but returns false on l1 as well
> ```

#### What is the problem?

Cannot merge or split expando instances.

#### Potential solutions

#### Give up on expando property/weakmap (works only on a dom element)

> new HtmlElement()..dataset['allow_layout_resize_this']='false';

Did not think of this, but the simplest.

#### Reflection

Obvious but currently needs 'dart:mirror' to make this work with any class instances.

#### Traversing the tree

Complex and ugly.

```
class Layout extends HtmlElement{
  Expando<bool> _freeze_resizing = new Expando<bool>();
  Layout.created():super.created();
  void add_resizable_attribute(HtmlElement e, bool isResizable) {
   _freeze_resizing[e] = !isResizable;
  }

  isFrozen(HtmlElement e,
     {bool search_down: true,
     bool search_up: true
     }) {
   ///resize allowed by default
   bool v;
   if (search_up) {
     Layout t = _get_topmost_layout();
     return t.isFrozen(
         e, search_down: true,
         search_up: false);
   } else if (search_down) {
     v = _freeze_resizing[e];
     v = v == null ? false : v;
     if (v) return true;
     return isFrozen_in_children(e);
   }
   return _freeze_resizing[e];
  }

  bool isFrozen_in_children(e) {
   for (var c in children) {
     if (c is! Layout) continue;
     if (c.isFrozen(
         e,
         search_up: false,
         search_down: true
     )) return true;
   }
   return false;
  }

  Layout _get_topmost_layout() {
   Layout tm;
   var e = this;
   while (e is Layout) {
     tm = e;
     e = e.parent;
   }
   return tm;
  }
  void _enforce_owner_exclusive_expando(element,[bool search_up=true]){
    ///remove expando properties from non-owner
    if(!children.contains(element)){
      _freeze_resizing[element]=null;
    }
    void enforce_on_children(){
      for(var c in children){
        if(c is! Layout) continue;
         c._enforce_owner_exclusive_expando(element,false);
      }
    }
    if(search_up){
      var tm = _get_topmost_layout();
      tm._enforce_owner_exclusive_expando(element,false);
    }else{
      enforce_on_children();
    }
  }
  append(e){
    super.append(e);
    _enforce_owner_exclusive_expando(element);
  }
}
```

Generally the problem can be circumvented and Dart is still easier than javascript. This is, however, the first ever time I have found Dart frustrating.

How would you solve an issue like this?

Comment: Perhaps you did not know but Expando in Dart (both Dart VM and dart2js) is in fact technically a WeakMap implementation (even if this not mentioned in documentation). I do not think that using WeakMap is a good solution to share dynamically added properties. It was only useful information about Expando nature. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/16172 https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/5144

Comment: Thanks for relying for that terribly written post(It was shocking). As you pointed, expando is a weakmap (although in browser, only key is weak and the value survives GC I heard, maybe I'm wrong) and it's not the best thing for sharing. I used it to prevent the map keeping the object alive. But then, you gave me an idea, I could simply remove both the key and the value when remove or replace gets called on my custom layout...  and to think about it, I can use object's hash as a key, so the whole fuss was pretty stupid. I will try it tomorrow

Comment: [Use WeakMap to support Expando if available](https://codereview.chromium.org/1599393003/patch/20001/30002)

Comment: @Dangling Feet, thanks for the comment, I'm a bit sick now and not confident but weakmap does not seem to have keys method for fetching keys, so extending can't be a solution. As to the github links you posted, people there are only confused about the difference between weakref and weakmap. I guess what I'm seeing is the dart's rare weakness and the solutions are using the standard map and hashCode combination, tree traversal or just simply avoiding the design.

Comment: @TastyCatFood what do you mean by "objects hash"? If you mean "object.hashCode", that doesn't uniquely identify an instance. Either the instances maintain their own unique ids, otherwise you can only use the object reference itself as unique key.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Thank you. That means using hashCode and map to replace expando is out of options then. I'm interested in this particular problem because this seems dart only issue;although dart:mirros easily solves this. Most unmodified dart class instances cannot be modified dynamically, which is a good thing, and one of expando's use cases is to stick properties on those and simulate dynamically added properties. Ideally, for the role, expando properties should be a little more versatile. Or it's just my temperature, my sanity is saying you hardly ever need it so forget it.

Comment: I haven't dealt with this use case and I didn't verify the statements made above. I just wanted to point out that `hashCode` is doesn't uniquely identify an object. What exactly is the problem with using an instance as key instead of the hashcode? If you miss something, please create an issue in the GitHub repo. If no one askes for a feature, there is no reason to add it.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I've posted a feature request along with the code [link](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Weakmap like structure with keys method

Yay, I've finally solved this!!!!
https://github.com/TastyCatFood/mistletoe

Has keys method

```
import 'package:mistletoe/mistletoe.dart';
void main(){
    var m = new Mistletoe();
    var t = new DateTime.now();
    m.add( t, 'hi', 'bye');
    print(m.keys(t));//prints 'hi'
    print(m.value(t,'hi'));//prints bye; 
    t = null;
    //With t garbage collected, m is empty now
}
```

Support for pseudo dynamic addition of properties

```
import 'package:mistletoe/mistletoe.dart';
Dynamism d = new Dynamism(expert:true);
void main(){
    var o = new Object();
    d.on(o).set('greetings',()=>print('hello world'));
    d.on(o).invoke('greetings');//prints hello world
    o = null;
    //With o garbage collected, d is empty now. 
}
```

I requested the feature here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25781
published: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mistletoe